# Ambiguous column "period" when exporting a bestsellers report

Tags: php, magento

In my Magento installation I tried to export a bestsellers report I just generated, and it produces the following error
`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'period' in field list is ambiguous`

If I configure the From - To Period to be less broad (to a month instead of 6 months) the report gets exported to CSV without a hassle.

Anyone has an idea where/how I could tackle this error? Couldn't also find any related topics addressing this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried prefacing "period" with the tablename, as in: tablename.period?

Comment: I know what you mean but to be honest, I don't know where I should start looking for that logic :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this error, but now able to resolve this issue. Just Edit this file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php

From - protected $_exportPageSize = 1000;

To   - protected $_exportPageSize = 1000000;