# Bestseller product report export

Tags: magento, export, report

I am exporting bestseller product report from Admin > report > product > bestseller.
It is working for few records.
If i add more days it gives below error

Can anyone have solution for this? is it export limit issue or bestseller report issue?

`a:5:{i:0;s:748:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'period' in field list is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT MAX(DATE_FORMAT(period, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS period, SUM(qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered, sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily_2.product_id, MAX(product_name) AS product_name, MAX(product_price) AS product_price, MAX(DATE_FORMAT(period, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS period, SUM(qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered, sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily.product_id, MAX(product_name) AS product_name, MAX(product_price) AS product_price FROM sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily AS sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily_2`

ref: 
[Ambiguous column "period" when exporting a bestsellers report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872640/ambiguous-column-period-when-exporting-a-bestsellers-report/36912234)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Sorry, But this question is related to programming. It gives error in sql query.

Comment: It seems to me that you're using Magento and you're getting a SQL error - that's not programming. It doesn't seem like you are writing your own SQL queries.